# Automatically reloading layer when source is changed

Tags: openlayers

I have a `ol.layer.Vector` that regularily changes its source. How do I perform a reload of the source everytime I change it?

Comment: calling `source.refresh()` should be sufficient

Comment: no, this throws nothing but a change event. I want the loader method  given in the source's constructor to be called.

Comment: depending on the loading strategy you may need to use `source.clear()`

Comment: @TomazicM  The question has almost certainly been asked before but the answer about reloading tile layers isn't relevant to a question about vector layers

Comment: @Mike Yes, you are right. We all overlooked this (subtle) difference.